# Update data in local SQLite then return to parent Activity solution

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I am learning Android. I am creating an application that have 2 activities: List Activity list all records from a local SQLite and Edit activity will create/update record.

On Edit activity, I have a button. When the button clicked, I will process creating/updating the record then returning back to parent activity (List activity).

On Button click. I have 2 solutions to process Create/Update:

**1. Process Create/Update in UI thread ( Not using AsyncTask )**

This solution is fine but I may have to show 'Processing' dialog.

**2. Use AsyncTask -- so creating/updating happens in background Thread**. Here is my code in Edit Activity:

---- **NOTE that Edit activity use Fragment so getActivity() method will return the instance of EditActivity**

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    AsyncTask<Phrase, Integer, Integer> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Phrase, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Phrase... params) {
            Phrase phrase = params[0];
            if (phrase._id > 0) {
                PhraseDao.update(DbManager.openWrite(getActivity()), phrase);
            } else {
                PhraseDao.insert(DbManager.openWrite(getActivity()), phrase);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

            // Close Edit Activity then Go back to List activity
            getActivity().finish();

            // MY QUESTION: What happens if the EditActivity (getActivity) already destroyed?

            // How can I handle destroyed activity here
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute(a_phrase);
}
```

});

**I don't know how to handle 'onPostExecute' method in the case Edit Activity ( accessed by getActivity()) Already destroyed.**

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null check to see if activity exists i.e

```
  if(getActivity() != null){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    getActivity().finish();
  }
```